# How to use key press events in nightwatch js?

Tags: selenium, nightwatch.js

I have a case where I need to press "Enter" button to navigate on my web application (System under test).

I did achieved this using Selenium- Java using Robot class,

```
Robot robot = new Robot();
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```

Can I do the same using nightwatch js ?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say for certain without any details about **why** you're pressing enter or what pressing enter does on your application.  As long as pressing enter is interacting with something inside the web browser (not a native OS window or application) then you should be able to use anything that is based on WebDriver API.

So I would say: Yes.

Answer (score 0):

You can try following way to press any key in nightwatch.js, i am pressing T and it is working superb!!

```
client.keys("t", function(done) {
    client.pause(5000);
    client.expect.element('#carousel_container').to.have.css('display').which.equals('block');
});
```

we are using above way because nightwatch.js Keys does not have any alphabet command in it's array, i have consoled and i haven't found any alphabet to press it.

```
Keys:
{ NULL: '',
  CANCEL: '',
  HELP: '',
  BACK_SPACE: '',
  TAB: '',
  CLEAR: '',
  RETURN: '',
  ENTER: '',
  SHIFT: '',
  CONTROL: '',
  ALT: '',
  PAUSE: '',
  ESCAPE: '',
  SPACE: '',
  PAGEUP: '',
  PAGEDOWN: '',
  END: '',
  HOME: '',
  LEFT_ARROW: '',
  UP_ARROW: '',
  RIGHT_ARROW: '',
  DOWN_ARROW: '',
  ARROW_LEFT: '',
  ARROW_UP: '',
  ARROW_RIGHT: '',
  ARROW_DOWN: '',
  INSERT: '',
  DELETE: '',
  SEMICOLON: '',
  EQUALS: '',
  NUMPAD0: '',
  NUMPAD1: '',
  NUMPAD2: '',
  NUMPAD3: '',
  NUMPAD4: '',
  NUMPAD5: '',
  NUMPAD6: '',
  NUMPAD7: '',
  NUMPAD8: '',
  NUMPAD9: '',
  MULTIPLY: '',
  ADD: '',
  SEPARATOR: '',
  SUBTRACT: '',
  DECIMAL: '',
  DIVIDE: '',
  F1: '',
  F2: '',
  F3: '',
  F4: '',
  F5: '',
  F6: '',
  F7: '',
  F8: '',
  F9: '',
  F10: '',
  F11: '',
  F12: '',
  COMMAND: '',
  META: '' 
},
```

You can press any key in above array easily like "client.keys(client.Keys.ENTER);".

Answer (score 0):

client.keys(client.Keys.ENTER);

Using the above code you can click an `ENTER` event on the form.